# How to know when each [HttPost] annotation of my controller class will be triggered?

Tags: asp.net-core, controller

I haven't used .NET framework in a while and I lack practice. A friend of mine started working in a project with me, and I am reading his codes to add new features to the project.

When I go to my controller class, I see that there are many `[HttpPost]` annotations and I don't know when each method associated to these annotations will be invoked, can anybody help me understand when specifically each method will be called?

I will share code snippet of my controller:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
        // Some code here
        [...]

        // POST: ClientController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateClientDto clientdto)
        {
            // Some code here
            [...]
        }

        // POST: ClientController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
           // Some code here
           [...]
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetList()
        {
            // Some code here
            [...]
        }

        // POST: ClientController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
          // Some code here
          [...]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View, there may be some `form`, `ajax` or other requests. For example, take `Create` action as an example:

If you use `form`:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Client" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Description" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
</form>
```

`method` specifies that your http request is `post`, `asp-controller` specifies the controller you want to access, and `asp-action` specifies the action in controller you want to request.

If you use `ajax`:

```
<button onclick="Test()">Click me</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function Test()
        {
            var data = {
                Name: "Name1",
                Description: "Des1"
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Client/Create',
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Successfully received Data ');
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed to receive the Data');
                    console.log('Failed ');
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

`type` specifies that the HTTP request is `POST`, and the format of `url` is generally `{controller}/{action}+{param}`, which means that you will send a request to the action of the controller, and `data` is the data you want to pass.

No matter which method you use, the final request should be  `{controller}/{action}`, such as `Client/Create`. You can check where these paths are located to determine how the request was made and which method was requested.

You can check such information in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a form with the post method in the view. When the form is posted, it will invoke the method with HttpPost annotation.

Comment: Which one of the HttpPost method will be invoked specifically, that's my question, cause there are many.